# Compilation error while using to_string in c++ program

Tags: c++, tostring

To get precision and scale of a number i am using this simple program. But while converting number into string it is giving compilation error.

```
g++ precision.cpp
precision.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
precision.cpp:6: error: ‘to_string’ was not declared in this scope
```

When I compile with the `-std=c++0x` switch I get

```
g++ precision.cpp  -std=c++0x
precision.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
precision.cpp:6: error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(int)’ is ambiguous
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2604: note: candidates are: std::string std::to_string(long long int)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2610: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long long unsigned int)
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/basic_string.h:2616: note:                 std::string std::to_string(long double)
```

The source code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string value = to_string(static_cast<int>(1234));
    int precision = value.length();
    int scale = value.length()-value.find('.')-1;
    cout << precision << " " << scale;
    return 0;
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: "`candidates are: std::string std::to_string(long long int)`" - why don't you try passing it one of the candidate types???

Comment: Thats' strange, i used your code and it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is because [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a C++11 feature, and GCC by default compiles in C++03 mode.

The second error, when you are using the correct flag, is *probably* because the support for C++11 in GCC 4.4 (which you seem to be using) is quite minimal. As you can see by the error messages, the compiler shows you the alternatives it have.

By the way, you don't need to cast integer literals to `int`, they are of type `int` by default. You *might* want to cast it to `long double` though, as that's one of the valid overloads and you seems to want to find the decimal point (the code will not work as expected if there is no decimal point in the string, like when converting an integer).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. with this output is 11 and 4. string value = to_string(static_cast<long double>(1234.56));

I don't understand why value.length() is 11 in this case.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Try to print the string inside quotes, like e.g. `std::cout << "The string is \"" << value << "\"\n";` It might contain spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use boost::lexical_cast instead.